# Does anybody know how to use mypy to generate stubs for the blender API including doc strings

Tags: python, blender, mypy

Does anybody know how to use mypy (https://github.com/python/mypy) to generate stub files for the blender python API (https://www.blender.org)?

Regards,

shodz

Comment: Might not be as simple as you want. Most of blenders api is defined in it's C/C++ code. I believe most of it comes from the makesrna files, for example a curve points select property is defined [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_curve.c;529cc364f4a6e02d149da89c934c486051801e1a$764) with `RNA_def_property(srna, "select", PROP_BOOLEAN, PROP_NONE);` so you should be able to generate a stub by altering the makesrna code that blender uses to build its bpy module.

Comment: Actually [rna_dump.py](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/python/rna_dump.py) may be close to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have experimented. I generate some stub files, but I am unable to generating the C/C++ files.